# TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6

I'm going to make a puzzle game.
When I clik the puzzle, it can't move and show an output error.

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
at Puzzles_fla::MainTimeline/dragObjek()
at Puzzles_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
at Puzzles_fla::MainTimeline/btn_1()
```

My code is

```
var ypos:int;
var xpos:int;
dragObjek(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12); // definisi bagian" dari puzzle

menu1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_menu1);

function btn_menu1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(1); // untuk kembali ke menu
}

function getPos(target:Object){
    xpos = target.x;
    ypos = target.y;
}

function startdrag(event:MouseEvent){
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    getPos(event.target);
}

function stopdrag(event:MouseEvent){
    if(event.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName(event.target.name+"Target"))){
       event.target.x = getChildByName(event.target.name+"Target").x;
       event.target.y = getChildByName(event.target.name+"Target").y;
       }else{
    event.target.x = xpos;
    event.target.y = ypos;
       }
       event.target.stopDrag();
}

function dragObjek(... objects){
    for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startdrag);
        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopdrag);
    }
```

I am using AS3 on Adobe Flash CS6.
The puzzle can't be drag and I can't go back to the Menu frame.

Comment: You're passing numbers thru `objects`, and generally these don't have an `addEventListener` property defined thru hierarchy... If you want to pass display objects, you'll need to replace these numbers. I don't remember very well of Flash api, but someone will help u probably :]

Comment: @DimasAditya What are the names of your puzzle pieces on the timeline?